# Present simple in a sub clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Is there any difference between

Let's wait until the rain has stopped.

and

Let's wait until the rain stop.

If not, then why my grammar book recommends the former.

Comment: "Let's wait until the rain stop" is wrong.  Did you mean "until the rain **stops**", which would be the correct present simple conjugation?

Comment: Both _stops_ and _has stopped_ are idiomatic, but you will probably go out of doors _after_ it has stopped raining rather than at the exact moment that it stops.